# Time series forecast cross-validation

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation, arima

The project im working based on hourly time series of the Belgian Electricity Price  for the period 2010-01-04 to 2016-10-30. And my datasets are the above :

Train Set :

```
> dput(head(data1))
structure(list(datetime_utc = c("2010-01-04 00:00:00", "2010-01-04 01:00:00", 
"2010-01-04 02:00:00", "2010-01-04 03:00:00", "2010-01-04 04:00:00", 
"2010-01-04 05:00:00"), Generation_BE = c(13143.7, 13143.7, 13143.7, 
13143.7, 13143.7, 13143.7), Generation_FR = c(63599, 62212, 62918, 
62613, 62432, 63411), Prices.BE = c(37.15, 33.47, 28, 21.29, 
16.92, 28), holidaysBE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Test Set :

```
> dput(head(data2))
structure(list(datetime_utc = c("2016-10-24 00:00:00", "2016-10-24 01:00:00", 
"2016-10-24 02:00:00", "2016-10-24 03:00:00", "2016-10-24 04:00:00", 
"2016-10-24 05:00:00"), Generation_BE = c(9615.7075, 9626.865, 
9648.0025, 9668.42, 9681.805, 9688.425), Generation_FR = c(45605L, 
44629L, 44073L, 44359L, 44056L, 44799L), Prices.BE = c(44.6, 
40.92, 37.39, 36.4, 33.01, 37.89), holidaysBE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**I should use a time series forecasting method to forecast the time series of Belgian Prices (Prices.Be) considering a horizon of 168 (hourly forecasts for the next 7 days). For this construction i must use the Train Set data.**

I have made the time series :

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

colSums(is.na(data1))
newdata1 <- data1 %>% 
  mutate(across(where(~ is.numeric(.) && anyNA(.)), 
                na.aggregate, FUN = median)) 
colSums(is.na(newdata1))
# Extract Belgium prices time series from data 
belgiump_ts <- ts(newdata1$Prices.BE, start = as.Date("2001-01-01"), frequency = 365*24)
```

*So, i decided to select the ARIMA model in order to achieve forecasting the time series.*
**The problem, Im facing is that i cant figure out how can i create cross-validation of ARIMA forecast ???**
Im quite confused about this and i cant understand how to face these difficulties. I cant think about how i can start buildind this.

Comment: Can you check [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscvexample/) or [here](http://freerangestats.info/blog/2019/07/20/time-series-cv) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection)

Comment: I have studied the first example you sended and i cant make my own arima model , cross validation is something misunderstanding for me , i will try again thanks @akrun